# What does the word "Action" do in a Scala function definition using the Play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am developing Play application and I've just started with Scala. I see that there is this word `Action` after the equals sign in the function below and before curly brace.

```
def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.index("Hi there"))
}
```

What does this code do? I've seen it used with `def index = {` but not with the word before the curly brace.

I would assume that the name of the function is `index`. But I do not know what the word `Action` does in this situation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The other answers deal with your specific case. You asked about the general case, however, so I'll attempt to answer from that perspective.

First off, `def` is used to define a *method*, [**not** a *function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala) (better to learn that difference now). But, you're right, `index` is the name of that method.

Now, unlike other languages you might be familiar with (e.g., C, Java), Scala lets you define methods with an expression (as suggested by the use of the assignment operator syntax, `=`). That is, everything after the `=` is an *expression* that will be evaluated to a *value* each time the method is invoked.

So, whereas in Java you have to say:

```
public int three() { return 3; }
```

In Scala, you can just say:

```
def three = 3
```

Of course, the expression is usually more complicated (as in your case). It could be a block of code, like you're more used to seeing, in which case the value is that of the last expression in the block:

```
def three = {
   val a = 1
   val b = 2
   a + b
}
```

Or it might involve a method invocation on some other object:

```
def three = Numbers.add(1, 2)
```

The latter is, in fact, exactly what's going on in your specific example, although it requires a bit more explanation to understand why. There are two bits of magic involved:

1. If an object has an `apply` method, then you can treat the object as if it were a *function*. You can say, for example, `Add(1, 2)` when you really mean `Add.apply(1,2)` (assuming there's an `Add` object with an `apply` method, of course). And just to be clear, it doesn't have to be an object defined with the `object` keyword. Any object with a suitable `apply` method will do.
2. If a method has a single *by-name* parameter (e.g., `def ifWaterBoiling(fn: => Tea)`), then you can invoke the method like `ifWaterBoiling { makeTea }`. The code in that block is evaluated lazily (and may not be evaluated at all). This would be equivalent to writing `ifWaterBoiling({ makeTea })`. The `{ makeTea }` part just defines an expression that gets passed in, unevaluated, for the `fn` parameter.

Comment: What is makeTea in #2?

Comment: @Programmer In this case, `makeTea` can be replaced with any expression that evaluates to a `Tea` object. For the sake of the example, I'm assuming the existence of a Tea-valued, nullary `makeTea` function.

Answer (score 17):

This word is a part of Play Framework, and it's an [object](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action$), which has method `apply(block: ⇒ Result)`, so your code is actually:

```
def index: Action[AnyContent] = Action.apply({
  Ok.apply(views.html.index("Hi there"))
})
```

Your `index` method returns an instance of the [class](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action) `Action[AnyContent]`.

By the way, you're passing a block of code `{Ok(...)}` to `apply` method, which (block of code) is actually acts as anonymous function here, because the required type for `apply`'s input is not just `Result` but `⇒ Result`, which means that it takes an anonymous function with no input parameters, which returns `Result`. So, your Ok-block will be executed when container, received your instance of class `Action` (from index method), decided to execute this block. Which simply means that you're just describing an action here - not executing - it will be actually executed when Play received your request - and find binding to your action inside routing file.

Also, you don't have to use `def` here as you always return same action - `val` or `lazy val` is usually enough. You will need a `def` only if you actually want to pass some parameter from routing table (for instance):

```
GET   /clients/:id          controllers.SomeController.index(id: Long)

def index(id: Long) = Action { ... } // new action generated for every new request here
```

Another possible approach is to choose Action, based on parameter:

```
def index(id: Long) = {
   if (id == 0) Action {...} else Action{...}
}
```

But uasually you can use routing table itself for that, which is better for decoupling. This example just shows that `Action` is nothing more than return value.

---

Update for @Kazuya

```
 val method1 = Action{...} //could be def too, no big difference here

 // this (code inside Action) gonna be called separately after "index" (if method2 is requested of course)
 // notice that it needs the whole request, so it (request) should be completely parsed at the time
 val method2 = Action{ req => // you can extract additional params from request
   val param1 = req.headers("header1")
   ...
 }

 //This is gonna be called first, notice that Play doesn't need the whole request body here, so it might not even be parsed on this stage
 def index(methodName: String) = methodName match {
   case "method1" => method1
   case "method2" => method2
 }
```

GWT/Scala.js use simillar approach for client-server interaction. This is just one possible solution to explain importance of the parameter "methodName" passed from routing table. So, action could be thought as a wrapper over function that in its turn represents a reference to OOP-method, which makes it useful for both REST and RPC purposes.

Comment: I don't understand **So, your Ok-block will be executed when container, received your instance of class Action (from index method), decided to execute this block** well.  In your explanation, the return value `Action` has two roles? One is the container of whole actions and another is just the return value?

Comment: @KazuyaTomita you basically return a "container" for the whole actions to the IoC-container (the Play Framework itself). So you can decide which action to return and Play can decide when to call your action. In practice (see my example from routing table), when Play receives a http-request it goes to a routing table, finds appropriate entry, extracts parameters from request (like id in the given example), asks you which action is appropriate (calling index function with id parameter), you return appropriate action, Play is executing it when it's ready (given its internal lifecycle, optimizatio

Comment: @KazuyaTomita notice that "id" value is still available inside Action (as a closure). So it's up to you which lifecycle stage is gonna be used for processing request parameter. you might wish to move your actions in a separate method, making them independent from one or several request parameters. You might think of it as the paramater is saying which method on the server is gonna be executed (so play's lifecycle performs kinda dispatching here). Some parameters, however, might be method parameters so you could close on them directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So, "a container for the whole actions"  is equal to the `Action` instance to be returned?   And very very sorry,,, I can't understand your explanation about "the lifecycle".   Could you give me another explanation?

Comment: yes, sorry it was a typo, I meant action, singular, not plural. By lifecycle (request lifecycle)  I mean that in response to a low level request (on socket level) play should execute several steps, rougly it might be reading from socket stream, parsing, filtering, routing and determining appropriate action,, converting to Play's representation of request, maybe some other filtering, applying action, response, closing connection. You can read about this more in Play docs and sources. The point is it might need to do some internal stuff between getting returned Action and actually executing it.

Comment: Let me summarize.  In your explanation, a container for an action in a controller is an `Action` instance and then it will be thrown to PlayFramework itself.   And in term of "lifecycle" I feel so sorry that I am still not clear.  I understand Play has some internal processes which is not visible. What do you mean by "you might wish to move your actions in a separate method" and "the paramater is saying which method on the server is gonna be executed"?   On last your response, you have explained internal things, but for me what you said seems to be a coding level, not internal stuffs.

Comment: your questions aren't really related to a lifecycle. The only reason why I brought this term up is to make it clear that Play makes two calls: first is to obtain appropriate action (which could be perceived as a reference to a method), second is to actually call that method, so it's quite logical to define those methods explicitly. Talking about parameters - some params might just say which action to execute (like id in my example). Some will become actual paramaters to the chosen Action, I'll add an example to my answer, basically Im pointing to the simillarities with GWT, Scala.js etc.

Comment: @KazuyaTomita I've dated the answer for you with some examples

Comment: Note that by method I mean OOP-method, not HTTP-method

Comment: I can understand the whole explanation, but why did you mention Play's internal processes which include reading socket, parsing, filtering and something like that?   You already explained why you mentioned it, namely you just wanted to show Play has two types of call.   Is this so important?   Now I can understand what you said(Thank you very very much), but I don't understand why you explained it suddenly.   Sorry for my persisting comments.

Comment: I don't anderstand what and why asking anymore, sorry

Answer (score 4):

Its the `Action` being called on with an expression block as argument. (The `apply` method is used under the hood).

```
Action.apply({
  Ok("Hello world")
})
```

A simple example (from [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaActionsComposition)) is as follows (look at comments in code):

```
case class Logging[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] {

  def apply(request: Request[A]): Result = {// apply method which is called on expression
    Logger.info("Calling action")
    action(request) // action being called on further with the request provided to Logging Action
  }

  lazy val parser = action.parser
}
```

Now you can use it to wrap any other action value:

```
def index = Logging { // Expression argument starts
  Action { // Action argument (goes under request)
    Ok("Hello World")
  }
}
```

Also, the case you mentioned for `def index = {` is actually returning `Unit` like: `def index: Unit = {`.