# Scala - Cannot use a method returning play.api.mvc.Result as a Handler for requests

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have this controller in Scala:

```
def commonRedirect(anId: Long) = {
implicit val aRule = CommonClient.getTheRule(anId)
aRule match {
  case false ⇒ Redirect("/general-rule/" + anId)
  case true  ⇒ Redirect("/custom-rule/" + anId)
}
```

}

but, this result in the error: "Cannot use a method returning play.api.mvc.Result as a Handler for requests".

If I apply an Action Builder, it works, but this is not the way that I want.

Any ideas to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify how you want to use `commonRedirect`. I have no errors with your code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to make an `Action`.

```
def commonRedirect(anId: Long) = Action {
  implicit val aRule = CommonClient.getTheRule(anId)
  aRule match {
    case false ⇒ Redirect("/general-rule/" + anId)
    case true  ⇒ Redirect("/custom-rule/" + anId)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @paul-draper. I found in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28247637/1665906 that  the required type for that is not just `Result` but `⇒ Result`, and that is an Action.